# How to flatten the given table?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Consider a table

```
Table1 = Flatten[Table[{x, y, {f1[x,y],f2[x,y],f3[x,y]}}, {x, 1, 2, 0.001}, {y, 
    2, 3, 0.001}],{1,2}];
```

Could you please tell me whether it is possible fastly to flatten it to the form

```
{{x1,y1,f1[x1,y1]},{x1,y1,f2[x2,y2]},{x1,y1,f3[x1,y1]},{x2,y2,f1[x2,y2]},...}
```

Comment: Consider generating the table this way instead: `Table1 = Flatten[Table[{x, y, f[x,y]}, {x, 1, 2, 0.001}, {y, 2, 3, 0.001}, {f, {f1, f2, f3}}], 2]`

Comment: @MarcoB : the problem is that in my case `f` is `RandomGenerate` of 10 points (so fi corresponds to the ith point) from some domain that is determined by x,y. And it requires a lot of time for launching.

Comment: What do you mean by `RandomGenerate`? Like `RandomPoint`? I'm not familiar with that function. You may want to include that in the question then.

Comment: @MarcoB : excuse me, I mean flattened `RandomPoint[
 SomeRegion[x,y], 10]`, and fi corresponds to some function then evaluated at this random point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small teste example:

```
t = Table[{x, y, {f1[x, y], f2[x, y], f3[x, y]}}, {x, 1, 2, 0.5}, {y, 
    2, 3, 0.5}] ;
Flatten[Map[Thread, t, {2}], 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But does a similar operation exist assuming that t is already flattened (i.e., instead of t we have Flatten[t,{1,2}])? P.S. Nevermind, I have already made a modification. It's Flatten[Map[Thread, t, {1}], {1,2}].